# XML Serialization/Deserialization in C++

Tags: c++, xml-serialization, serialization, tinyxml

I am using C++ from Mingw, which is the windows version of GNC C++.

What I want to do is: serialize C++ object into an XML file and deserialize object from XML file on the fly. I check TinyXML. It's pretty useful, and (please correct me if I misunderstand it) it basically add all the nodes during processing, and finally put them into a file in one chunk using TixmlDocument::saveToFile(filename) function.

I am working on real-time processing, and how can I write to a file on the fly and append the following result to the file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice that each TiXmlBase Class has a Print method and also supports streaming to strings and streams.

You could walk the new parts of the document in sequence and output those parts as they are added, maybe?

Give it a try.....

Tony

Answer (score 3):

BOOST has a very nice Serialization/Deserialization lib [BOOST.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).
If you stream your objects to a boost xml [archive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/serialization/doc/archives.html#archive_models) it will stream them in xml format.
If xml is to big or to slow you only need to change the archive in a text or binary archive to change the streaming format.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better example of  C++ object serialization:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/XMLFoundation.aspx

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Link works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [gSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gsoap2) for this purpose. It is probably too powerful for just XML serialization, but knowing it can do much more means I do not have to consider other solutions for more advanced projects since it also supports WSDL, SOAP, XML-RPC, and JSON. Also suitable for embedded and small devices, since XML is simply a transient wire format and not kept in a DOM or something memory intensive.